# Connection profile with IBP 2.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have created an application with IBP 1 and the nodejs SDK for fabric. It works fine.

IBP1 is becoming "deprecated" and I am switching to IBP2. However, there are major differences with the connection profile "functionality".

In IBP 1, you just had to download the whole connection profile and you had all the information required. It was wonderful.

In IBP 2, connection profiles are "related to chaincodes" and contain very few information. Thus, my previous code just does not work with the current connection profile provided by the platform.

An example of error:  `error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: no suitable peers available to initialize from`

What should be the solution here?

- Is there a way to download full connection profile like we used to be able to do?
- Do we have to build the connection profile by our self? This would be, IMO, a major regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is that the answer to both of your questions is no. The connection profile you download requires you to use discovery, so in your gateway connection ensure you have enabled discovery and disabled the asLocalhost option
for example

```
await gateway.connect(ccp, {
            wallet: myWallet,
            identity: userNameWalletLabel,
            discovery: {enabled: true, asLocalhost: false}
        });
```

Comment: Correct, you need to ensure you define your anchor peers.